# Not formatting after 'hadoop namenode -format'. I am doing setup on aws

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, hdfs, hadoop2

I am trying to format namenode but don't know whats wrong here. 
I have done entry in /etc/hosts and core-site.xml but still i am not able to format drive.

```
[hduser@ec2-54-242-91-165 ~]$ hadoop namenode -format
    DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
    Instead use the hdfs command for it.

    2018-02-14 20:55:25,989 INFO  [main] namenode.NameNode (LogAdapter.java:info(47)) - STARTUP_MSG:
    /************************************************************
    STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
    STARTUP_MSG:   host = localhost/127.0.0.1
    STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
    STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.7.5
    STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /usr/local/hadoop/etc/:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-framework-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.54.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-sslengine-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-client-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.5-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.5-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-sharedcachemanager-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.5-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.7.5.jar
    STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://shv@git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 18065c2b6806ed4aa6a3187d77cbe21bb3dba075; compiled by 'kshvachk' on 2017-12-16T01:06Z
    STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_161
    ************************************************************/
    2018-02-14 20:55:25,999 INFO  [main] namenode.NameNode (LogAdapter.java:info(47)) - registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
    2018-02-14 20:55:26,001 INFO  [main] namenode.NameNode (NameNode.java:createNameNode(1441)) - createNameNode [-format]
    2018-02-14 20:55:26,590 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    Formatting using clusterid: CID-d4daffff-5e9b-4eba-9de0-a880e9de496d
    2018-02-14 20:55:26,943 INFO  [main] namenode.FSNamesystem (FSNamesystem.java:<init>(721)) - No KeyProvider found.
    2018-02-14 20:55:26,944 INFO  [main] namenode.FSNamesystem (FSNamesystemLock.java:<init>(120)) - fsLock is fair: true
    2018-02-14 20:55:26,947 INFO  [main] namenode.FSNamesystem (FSNamesystemLock.java:<init>(136)) - Detailed lock hold time metrics enabled: false
    2018-02-14 20:55:26,989 INFO  [main] blockmanagement.DatanodeManager (DatanodeManager.java:<init>(239)) - dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
    2018-02-14 20:55:26,990 INFO  [main] blockmanagement.DatanodeManager (DatanodeManager.java:<init>(245)) - dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check=true
    2018-02-14 20:55:26,991 INFO  [main] blockmanagement.BlockManager (InvalidateBlocks.java:printBlockDeletionTime(72)) - dfs.namenode.startup.delay.block.deletion.sec is set to 000:00:00:00.000
    2018-02-14 20:55:26,993 INFO  [main] blockmanagement.BlockManager (InvalidateBlocks.java:printBlockDeletionTime(77)) - The block deletion will start around 2018 Feb 14 20:55:26
    2018-02-14 20:55:26,995 INFO  [main] util.GSet (LightWeightGSet.java:computeCapacity(354)) - Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
    2018-02-14 20:55:26,995 INFO  [main] util.GSet (LightWeightGSet.java:computeCapacity(355)) - VM type       = 64-bit
    2018-02-14 20:55:26,997 INFO  [main] util.GSet (LightWeightGSet.java:computeCapacity(356)) - 2.0% max memory 966.7 MB = 19.3 MB
    2018-02-14 20:55:26,997 INFO  [main] util.GSet (LightWeightGSet.java:computeCapacity(361)) - capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,037 INFO  [main] blockmanagement.BlockManager (BlockManager.java:createBlockTokenSecretManager(385)) - dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,039 INFO  [main] blockmanagement.BlockManager (BlockManager.java:<init>(371)) - defaultReplication         = 3
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,040 INFO  [main] blockmanagement.BlockManager (BlockManager.java:<init>(372)) - maxReplication             = 512
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,041 INFO  [main] blockmanagement.BlockManager (BlockManager.java:<init>(373)) - minReplication             = 1
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,041 INFO  [main] blockmanagement.BlockManager (BlockManager.java:<init>(374)) - maxReplicationStreams      = 2
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,041 INFO  [main] blockmanagement.BlockManager (BlockManager.java:<init>(375)) - replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,041 INFO  [main] blockmanagement.BlockManager (BlockManager.java:<init>(376)) - encryptDataTransfer        = false
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,041 INFO  [main] blockmanagement.BlockManager (BlockManager.java:<init>(377)) - maxNumBlocksToLog          = 1000
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,054 INFO  [main] namenode.FSNamesystem (FSNamesystem.java:<init>(749)) - fsOwner             = hduser (auth:SIMPLE)
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,056 INFO  [main] namenode.FSNamesystem (FSNamesystem.java:<init>(750)) - supergroup          = supergroup
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,056 INFO  [main] namenode.FSNamesystem (FSNamesystem.java:<init>(751)) - isPermissionEnabled = true
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,057 INFO  [main] namenode.FSNamesystem (FSNamesystem.java:<init>(762)) - HA Enabled: false
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,059 INFO  [main] namenode.FSNamesystem (FSNamesystem.java:<init>(799)) - Append Enabled: true
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,169 INFO  [main] util.GSet (LightWeightGSet.java:computeCapacity(354)) - Computing capacity for map INodeMap
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,169 INFO  [main] util.GSet (LightWeightGSet.java:computeCapacity(355)) - VM type       = 64-bit
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,170 INFO  [main] util.GSet (LightWeightGSet.java:computeCapacity(356)) - 1.0% max memory 966.7 MB = 9.7 MB
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,171 INFO  [main] util.GSet (LightWeightGSet.java:computeCapacity(361)) - capacity      = 2^20 = 1048576 entries
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,174 INFO  [main] namenode.FSDirectory (FSDirectory.java:<init>(241)) - ACLs enabled? false
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,180 INFO  [main] namenode.FSDirectory (FSDirectory.java:<init>(245)) - XAttrs enabled? true
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,181 INFO  [main] namenode.FSDirectory (FSDirectory.java:<init>(253)) - Maximum size of an xattr: 16384
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,181 INFO  [main] namenode.NameNode (FSDirectory.java:<init>(304)) - Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,191 INFO  [main] util.GSet (LightWeightGSet.java:computeCapacity(354)) - Computing capacity for map cachedBlocks
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,196 INFO  [main] util.GSet (LightWeightGSet.java:computeCapacity(355)) - VM type       = 64-bit
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,197 INFO  [main] util.GSet (LightWeightGSet.java:computeCapacity(356)) - 0.25% max memory 966.7 MB = 2.4 MB
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,197 INFO  [main] util.GSet (LightWeightGSet.java:computeCapacity(361)) - capacity      = 2^18 = 262144 entries
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,198 INFO  [main] namenode.FSNamesystem (FSNamesystem.java:<init>(5147)) - dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,198 INFO  [main] namenode.FSNamesystem (FSNamesystem.java:<init>(5148)) - dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,198 INFO  [main] namenode.FSNamesystem (FSNamesystem.java:<init>(5149)) - dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 30000
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,201 INFO  [main] metrics.TopMetrics (TopMetrics.java:logConf(76)) - NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.window.num.buckets = 10
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,204 INFO  [main] metrics.TopMetrics (TopMetrics.java:logConf(78)) - NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.num.users = 10
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,205 INFO  [main] metrics.TopMetrics (TopMetrics.java:logConf(80)) - NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.windows.minutes = 1,5,25
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,211 INFO  [main] namenode.FSNamesystem (FSNamesystem.java:initRetryCache(908)) - Retry cache on namenode is enabled
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,216 INFO  [main] namenode.FSNamesystem (FSNamesystem.java:initRetryCache(916)) - Retry cache will use 0.03 of total heap and retry cache entry expiry time is 600000 millis
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,219 INFO  [main] util.GSet (LightWeightGSet.java:computeCapacity(354)) - Computing capacity for map NameNodeRetryCache
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,219 INFO  [main] util.GSet (LightWeightGSet.java:computeCapacity(355)) - VM type       = 64-bit
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,219 INFO  [main] util.GSet (LightWeightGSet.java:computeCapacity(356)) - 0.029999999329447746% max memory 966.7 MB = 297.0 KB
    2018-02-14 20:55:27,222 INFO  [main] util.GSet (LightWeightGSet.java:computeCapacity(361)) - capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
    Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory /tmp/hadoop-hduser/dfs/name ? (Y or N) Y
    2018-02-14 20:56:40,909 INFO  [main] namenode.FSImage (FSImage.java:format(176)) - Allocated new BlockPoolId: BP-1602166314-127.0.0.1-1518641800839
    2018-02-14 20:56:40,926 INFO  [main] common.Storage (NNStorage.java:format(568)) - Storage directory /tmp/hadoop-hduser/dfs/name has been successfully formatted.
    2018-02-14 20:56:40,945 INFO  [FSImageSaver for /tmp/hadoop-hduser/dfs/name of type IMAGE_AND_EDITS] namenode.FSImageFormatProtobuf (FSImageFormatProtobuf.java:save(413)) - Saving image file /tmp/hadoop-hduser/dfs/name/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 using no compression
    2018-02-14 20:56:41,108 INFO  [FSImageSaver for /tmp/hadoop-hduser/dfs/name of type IMAGE_AND_EDITS] namenode.FSImageFormatProtobuf (FSImageFormatProtobuf.java:save(416)) - Image file /tmp/hadoop-hduser/dfs/name/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 of size 323 bytes saved in 0 seconds.
    2018-02-14 20:56:41,123 INFO  [main] namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager (NNStorageRetentionManager.java:getImageTxIdToRetain(203)) - Going to retain 1 images with txid >= 0
    2018-02-14 20:56:41,125 INFO  [main] util.ExitUtil (ExitUtil.java:terminate(124)) - Exiting with status 0
    2018-02-14 20:56:41,126 INFO  [Thread-1] namenode.NameNode (LogAdapter.java:info(47)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:
    /************************************************************
    SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at localhost/127.0.0.1
    ************************************************************/
```

Comment: [hduser@ec2-54-242-91-165 ~]$ vi /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost       ec2-54-242-91-165.compute-1.amazonaws.com
#172-31-45-37 ec2-54-242-91-165.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: `Storage directory /tmp/hadoop-hduser/dfs/name has been successfully formatted`... First off, you shouldn't be storing your Hadoop data into `/tmp`. Secondly, is there a specific reason not to use EMR clusters?

Comment: Was there any more developments on this? I also am having this issue where the exit code is 0 but I have the same output